# How to shorten the text in second line?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a button with this setting in kv

```
Button:
    text: root.text
    text_size: (self.width, None)
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (100, 100)
    shorten: True
    background_normal: ''
```

So it gives me result like this

button output

[image]

as you can see this is shortening in one line but i want this to take 2 lines and if some text rest then get shorten.

i tried to put `max_lines: 2` but there is no change

Comment: change to `shorten: False`, docs: *...with shorten, the text is always one line...* https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.max_lines

Comment: You mean to say that i should use only `max_lines: 2` property???
well in that case this is giving me very unexpected result